# AWS IAM: How to prevent privilege elevation with IAM policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

There is a policy attached to user/role which is allowed to create other policies and roles, but, for example, original role doesn't have permissions to do `s3:PutObject`. Is there any way I can prevent this role/user from creating another policy which allows `s3:PutObject` and elevating it's own permissions by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grant users the ability to create policies and roles, then you trust them not to abuse it. Very few admins should have this ability.

The way to solve your case is for an uber-admin to create policies and roles, and for your user to be restricted to which policies/roles he can attach (see [related article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-a-limited-iam-administrator-by-using-managed-policies/)). You can also implement automation to validate the policies created by your uber-admins meet certain conditions.